React-native-modal-datetime-picker: If we select todays date but 18 years ago, it is incorrectly selecting current year
Version: "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0"
`<DateTimePickerModal
locale="en_GB"
maximumDate={endDate}
minimumDate={initDate}
display="inline"
isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
mode="date"
onConfirm={handleConfirm}
onCancel={hideDatePicker}
/>`

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    console.log("A date has been picked: ", date);
    setDate(date)
    hideDatePicker();
  };
  const endDate = new Date();
  endDate.setFullYear(endDate.getFullYear() - 18);

  const initDate = new Date();
  initDate.setFullYear(initDate.getFullYear() - 100);

If i try to select todays date but 18 years ago say 18 April 2006, it is selecting 18 April 2024, this is happening only for current date and only in IOS.

Fixed, as per this https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/issues/578, it was taking the default loaded time for IOS, so had to add                       date={endDate} so it takes the endDate as the default date
